# Solving this PDE: $ \frac{\partial}{\partial t}F(s,t) = \frac{a}{2}(1-F(s,t))^2$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations

I encountered this differential equation in mathematical biology. How can I solve it?

$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial t}F(s,t) = \frac{a}{2}(1-F(s,t))^2

$$

and 
$$
F(s,0)=s
$$

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Fix $s$ and consider $g(t)=F(s,t)$. Then $g'=\frac12a(1-g)^2$ hence $\frac{g'}{(1-g)^2}=\frac12a$, which yields $\frac1{1-g(t)}=\frac12at+\frac1{1-g(0)}$. Since $g(0)=s$,
$$
F(s,t)=\frac{at+(2-at)s}{at+2-ats}=\frac{2s+at(1-s)}{2+at(1-s)}.
$$